# JMS MQ connection pooling in WAS 7

Tags: jms, connection-pooling, ibm-mq, websphere-7

We are using JMS to communicate with WebSphere MQ [V7] using WebSphere Application Server [V7]. Application is heavy with a load of around 4-5 tps. We use connection factory along with a sender and receive queue to implement synchronous MQ operation. Currently, the connection factory has been defined as static and the queues are obtained through a JNDI lookup for each request.

**From a performance perspective do we need explicitly implement a connection pool such as Apache commons pool or would connection pooling offered by WAS suffice?**

The JMS settings have been configured in WAS based on the expected load.